# use $filter service inside module.config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

As per the AngularJS documentation it seems that it is only possible inject providers in `module.config`.
However, I have to configure some 3rd party service using its provider `ServiceXProvider` and set it up like this:

`ServiceXProvider.format = function format(x) { return $filter('date')(x, "yyyy-MM-dd"); }`

`$filter` is obviously a service and not a provider and I can not inject it into the `module.config`.

Is there any reasonable workaround for this scenario?

Comment: try it in a `run()` block, can inject anything there

Comment: @charlietfl, this actually happened to be a good idea at least in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a provider object in a `run()` block where you can inject services

Comment: It turned out that I could not inject the provider itself but rather an instance of the service. Because of the ServiceX's implementation, setting the `format` method on the instance and not on the provider worked. I am accepting your answer, however, since it helped me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As @charlietfl suggested it was possible in this case to inject `ServiceX` instance in `module.run()` (not the provider but the instance).

So

```
module.config(function (ServiceXProvider, $filter) {
  ServiceXProvider.format = function format(x) { return $filter('date')(x, "yyyy-MM-dd"); }
});
```

became

```
module.run(function (ServiceX, $filter) {
  ServiceX.format = function format(x) { return $filter('date')(x, "yyyy-MM-dd"); }
});
```

It is not perfect but as far as I am concerned it works. Notice ServiceXProvider became ServiceX later.